# Что не так с программой или чего не хватает

Tags: c++, c

Программа создающая и заполняющая массив одной собственной функцией,а другой собственной функцией сортирует методом "Вставок",но сортировка проводится если элементов массива меньше 9,почему так?Чего не хватает в программе?

Код программы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

void fill_and_print_array(int arr[], int N)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0;i < N;i++)
    {
        printf("arr[%d]",i);
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);    
    }
    for(i = 0;i < N;i++)
    {
        printf("%3d",arr[i]);   
    }
}

void mass_sort(int arr[], int N)
{
    int i,newElement, location;
    for (i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        newElement = arr[i];
        location = i - 1;
        while(location >= 0 && arr[location] > newElement)
        {
            arr[location+1] = arr[location];
            location = location - 1;
        }
        arr[location+1] = newElement;
    }
    printf("\nОтсортированный массив методом вставок имеет вид:\n");
    for(i = 1; i < N;i++)
    {
         printf("%3d",arr[i]);
    }
}

int main() 
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"Rus");
    const int N;
    int arr[N];
    printf("Введите количество элементов массива: ");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    fill_and_print_array(arr,N);
    mass_sort(arr,N);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: На каком языке эта программа написана? Ответ на ваш вопрос критически зависит от языка программирования. Почему на вопросе стоят тэги [C] и [C++] одновременно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int arr[N];
```

Чему в этом месте равно `N`?

Comment: В этот момент кода еще ничему,значение дается позже через scanf

Comment: @KotosKitosovich ... а массив волшебным образом это почувствует?

Comment: Значит надо scanf поставить до объявления массива?

Comment: Спасибо,разобрался всё работает

Comment: @Kotos Kitosovich: О каком "позже через scanf" может вообще идти речь, если переменная объявлена как `const`??? Это не говоря уже о том, что код в принципе не компилируем в C++.